# Python 3.6: trying to pip install numpy

Tags: numpy, python-3.6

I'm just trying a simple `pip3.6 install numpy`, and I get the following error:

```
distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('numpy>=1.7.0')
```

How can this be solved? I tried to upgrade `easy_install` but that did not work, neither did trying to install scikit-learn directly. Note that I already have been using python3.5.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, a bit above the error I ended up noticing:

```
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] 
 certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749) -- Some packages may not be found!
```

The problem was using a temporary different network and used:

```
pip3.6 install --trusted-host pypi.python.org numpy
```

which solved the issue for now.