# How to install pip on python 3.6, not the default python 2.7?

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, numpy, pip

So all day, I have been trying to install pip. I've executed `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py > get-pip.py`. Then `sudo python get-pip.py`. Next I went to install numpy with `sudo pip install numpy`. Finally, I opened up the python 3.6 IDLE and I tried to `import numpy as np` and got an error saying that the module didn't exist.

I found out that the pip was installed in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` so I deleted 2.7 from the directory. I redid the whole process again and got the same error :|

I'm wondering if I need to change the default `python` which I've been told is not wise. What do I do? I' sure I've deleted everything with python 2.7 in it?

MacBookAir OSX - Sierra

Or is there an alternate way that I can install numpy in python 3.6????

Comment: Is your 3.6 still in beta?  There have posts about `numpy` not working with the beta Python.  It'll be safer to stick with 3.5 until that's fully released.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40893602/how-to-install-numpy-for-python-3-6

Comment: But just now, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41316631/python-3-6-trying-to-pip-install-numpy

Comment: It was the newest version available, released a few days ago so I would guess that it is still in beta. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You shouldn't delete the system python. Delete nothing in `/Library/Python` or it's subfolders.

How did you install python 3.6? Usually, it'll be installed as `python3.6` with a symlink to `python3`. `pip3` is usually installed with it.

So what you probably wanted to do was:

```
pip3 install numpy
python3
>>> import numpy
```

Comment: `python3 -m pip` will also reliably use the python installation you want.

Comment: I downloaded python 3.6 straight from the python.org website. I will keep your first comment in mind and I'll try your suggestions. Thanks